# Wrong Compose file version

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed the Docker from: https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows

I downloaded some resource to run with docker and run `docker-compose up`.

Unfortunately I see:

```
ERROR: Version in ".\docker-compose.yml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version ("2.0", "2.1", "3.0") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

I checked the docker-compose version and I see:

```
> docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7afaa436
docker-py version: 2.0.2
CPython version: 2.7.13
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

I have no experience with Docker, but I suspect a version issue here. However I have no idea how to upgrade the docker-compose. Am I right? And how can I do it?

Update:
The `docker-compose.yml` begins like this

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    php:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `docker-compose version 1.11.1` is supported up to version "3.1" of *.yml file. (Your config is 3.4)

Update your `docker-compose` to latest(1.23.2) version to be able run compose files up to '3.7'

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#install-compose

Comment: And that's exactly my question. How do I update docker-compose on Windows?

Comment: are you sure that you have latest version of docker-for-windiws? The installation provides Docker Engine, Docker CLI client, Docker Compose, Docker Machine, and Kitematic. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#about-windows-containers

Comment: Or you can also just change `3.4` to `3.1`. And try run. - Maybe in yours config is no thing that requires version higher than 3.1.

Comment: You have exactly the old version. Download and reinstall. 
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/

Answer (score 1):

Your file `docker-compose.yml` has an error. You should either declare a valid version and place everything under services, like so:

```
version: '3'
service:
  service1:
    # ...
  service2:
    # ...
```

or omit the version and place all services in the root:

```
service1:
  # ...
service2:
  # ...
```

Comment: It works for my colleagues using Linux, so I suppose the `docker-compose.yml` file should be OK. It has version 3.4 declared, I added the sample in the question.